# Static variables are not being initialized

Tags: c, static

I'm using the Yagarto GCC compiler and I'm finding problems when using local static variables. All of them are initialized by me to zero when declaring it. But when debugging execution, I find they are not being initialized:

Example:

```
void hello( void ){
    static int number_hellos = 0;

    number_hellos++;

    printf("%d\n", number_hellos);

}
```

When debugger reaches `number_hellos++`, I find its initial value is not 0. Why? Is there any compiler or linker flag I should enable?

Comment: Could you provide the actual output of the debugger?

Comment: do you talk about the second  subsequent calls?

Comment: Did you try deactivating any compiler optimization?

Comment: this code is working fine in my ubuntu 12.04! This may be your compiler problem!

Comment: printf can be added before to the increment statement and checked.

Comment: Are you sure that this is the *exact* code that's causing issues? Please provide a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: this looks like a linker problem.  Generally, the appropriate start library must be the first executable in the link.  The startup library contains the code start.c  This code must be executed first.  If needed, this code can be replaced at link time.  This code (amongst other things) initializes the .bss segment to all 0x00 and copies the pre-initialized values to the .data segment.

Comment: What are the contents of your linker.cmd file?  Does your compile/link script include the startup library?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your help

Finally I detected the problem: The startup code was not correctly initializing the static variables. That's the reason why the execution arrives to the function hello, the static variable is unitialized.

A correct startup code fixes the problem.

Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

This static initialization:

```
static int number_hellos = 0;
```

happens only once. Actually in compile time. Not when entering the function.

Comment: But why would the value be different from `0` when you break at the statement where it's being increased?

Comment: Initialisation doesn't happen at compile time. It happens when application is launched.

Comment: But what about initialization with constant values "known" to the compiler?